# How can I color region between two lines specified by slope and intercept on a ggplot R in a log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to shade region between two lines specified by slope and intercept. The area which I need to shade is specified in between the grey lines. I tried using geom_ribbon but finding the points always fail.

The code and data is below:

```
pl=seq(1,12,1)
px=c(231071, 134666, 16420, 100681, 3178, 28996, 121, 222, 149101,119436, 24013, 745)
py=c(948, 941, 744, 660, 363, 78, 50, 5, 254, 17, 5, 293)
data_point<-data.frame(cbind(px,py,pl))

library(ggplot2)
p <- qplot(px, py, data = data_point)
    p+geom_abline(slope=0.56646,intercept=-0.22814,colour="black",fill="black",size=1)+
   geom_abline(slope=0.54266,intercept=-0.36599,colour="darkgrey",
 fill="darkgrey",size=1,alpha=0.6)+
 geom_abline(slope=0.59026,intercept=-0.14705,colour="darkgrey",
fill="darkgrey",size=1.5,alpha=0.6)+
scale_y_log10(breaks=c(1,2,5,10,25,50,100,200,400,600,1000))+
 scale_x_log10(breaks=c(20,50,300,2000,10000,50000,200000,300000)) +labs(x="N",y="h")+theme_bw()+
theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
axis.text=element_text(size=12),
axis.title=element_text(size=15),
axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

The code which I used to find the x,y co-ordinates is listed below. Since, I am using the log scale with base 10, I am taking it into consideration while calculating co-ordinates using slope and intercept.

```
x=c(1,15000,300000)
res <- data.frame(x = x,
                  y = (10 ^ (-0.22814)) + (x ** 0.56646),
                  ymin = (10 ^ (-0.36599)) +  (x ** 0.54266),
                  ymax = (10 ^ (-0.14705)) + (x ** 0.59026) )
res$x[which.min(res$x)] <- -Inf
res$x[which.max(res$x)] <- Inf
```

I have spent a lot of time in adding the grey region but no luck yet. I will really appreciate all the help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work...

```
hi <- list(slope=0.59026,intercept=-0.14705)
lo <- list(slope=0.54266,intercept=-0.36599)
f  <- function(x,p) with(p,10^(intercept+slope*log10(x)))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data_point,aes(x=px,y=py))+
  geom_abline(slope=0.56646,intercept=-0.22814,colour="black",fill="black",size=1)+
  geom_abline(slope=0.54266,intercept=-0.36599,colour="darkgrey",
              fill="darkgrey",size=1,alpha=0.6)+
  geom_abline(slope=0.59026,intercept=-0.14705,colour="darkgrey",
              fill="darkgrey",size=1.5,alpha=0.6)+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=f(px,hi),ymin=f(px,lo)),fill="green",alpha=0.2)+
  scale_y_log10(breaks=c(1,2,5,10,25,50,100,200,400,600,1000))+
  scale_x_log10(breaks=c(20,50,300,2000,10000,50000,200000,300000),expand=c(0,0)) +
  labs(x="N",y="h")+theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.title=element_text(size=15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

[image]

Note the use of `expand=c(0,0)` in `scale_x_log10(...)`. This causes the x-scale limits to be the same as `range(x)` (the default is to expand them a bit on either side). If you use the default, the colors do not extend all the way to the ends of the plot.

Also, please don't use, e.g., `df <- data.frame(cbind(px,py,...))`. Much better to use: `df<- data.frame(px,py,...)`.